# Memory allocation mistake on C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to split set of numbers to 2 different heaps, from their middle value. I used heap data structure to do this. i.e Input is 10 in this example. Apparently I am making some mistake while allocating memory, it gives the following output when I try to allocate dynamically:

```
[ 4 3 2 0 1 ]

[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

why the second heap is always 0 ?

Because if I uncomment the static memory allocation and use it instead, it gives true output which is:

```
[ 4 3 2 0 1 ]

[ 9 8 7 5 6 ]
```

I have tested my heap and other parts well enough, I am pretty sure the problem is on memory allocation but I couldn't find out where the mistake is.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
    int M = atoi(argv[1]);
    int pq_1_size = M / 2;
    int pq_2_size = M - pq_1_size;

    int *a;
    int *b;
    a = (int *)malloc(pq_1_size * sizeof(int));
    b = (int *)malloc(pq_2_size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < pq_1_size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    } 
    for (int j = pq_1_size; j < M; j++) {
        b[j] = j;
    }  
    //int a[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // if I use this section instead it works fine.
    //int b[5] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; // if I use this section instead it works fine.
    Heap someHeap = { 0, {0} };
    Heap *A = &someHeap;
    buildHeap(A, a, pq_1_size);
    //buildHeap(A, a, 5);
    print(A);
    printf("\n");   

    Heap anotherHeap = { 0, {0} };
    Heap *B = &anotherHeap;
    buildHeap(B, b, pq_2_size);
    //buildHeap(B, b, 5);
    print(B);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the heap code:

```
#define HEAPSIZE 500
#define left(i) ((i)<<1)
#define right(i) (((i)<<1)+1)
#define parent(i) ((i)>>1)

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int element[HEAPSIZE];
} Heap;

//Swaps the values of two ints a and b
void swap(int * a, int * b) {
    int temp;
    temp = * a;
    * a = * b;
    * b = temp;
}

//Ensures that the max heap property in heap A is satisfied at and below index i
void makeHeap(Heap * A, int i) {
    int largest = A->element[i];
    int position = i;
    int l = left(i);
    if(l <= A->size && A->element[l] > largest) {
        largest = A->element[l];
        position = l;
    }
    int r = right(i);
    if(r <= A->size && A->element[r] > largest) {
        largest = A->element[r];
        position = r;
    }
    if(i != position) {
        swap(&A->element[i], &A->element[position]);
        makeHeap(A, position);
    }
}

//Get the maximum value in the heap A
int extractMax(Heap * A) {
    if(!A->size) {
        puts("error: heap empty");
        return 0;   
    }
    int max = A->element[0];
    swap(&A->element[0], &A->element[A->size]);
    --A->size; 
    makeHeap(A, 0);
    return max;
}

//Increase the key of the ith element in heap A to be k
void increaseKey(Heap * A, int i, int k) {
    if(A->element[i] >= k) {
        printf("error: %d is less than the key of %d\n", k, i);
        return;
    }
    int position = i;
    while(position != 0 && A->element[parent(position)] < k) {
        A->element[position] = A->element[parent(position)];
        position = parent(position);
    }
    A->element[position] = k;
}

//Inserts the value i into the heap A
void insert(Heap * A, int i) {
    if(A->size >= HEAPSIZE) {
        printf("error: heap full\n");
        return;
    }
    A->element[A->size] = INT_MIN;
    increaseKey(A, A->size, i);
    ++A->size;
}

//Prints the heap A as an array
void print(Heap * A) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("[ ");
    for(i = 0; i < A->size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A->element[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

//Makes a heap out of an unsorted array a of n elements 
void buildHeap(Heap * A, int * a, int n) {
    if(n > HEAPSIZE) {
        printf("error: too many elements\n");
        return;
    }
    if(A->size) {
        printf("error: heap not empty\n");
        return;
    }
    int nbytes = n * sizeof(int);
    memcpy(A->element, a, nbytes);
    A->size = n;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = A->size/2; i >= 0; i--) {
        makeHeap(A, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Heap` and the code for `buildHeap()` and `print`?

Comment: i have posted it

Comment: As an aside: ["*Do I cast the result of malloc?*"](/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) **No.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that arrays are using index values starting from 0.

```c
    int pq_1_size = M / 2;
    int pq_2_size = M - pq_1_size;   << This is either M/2 or M/2+1

    a = (int *)malloc(pq_1_size * sizeof(int));
    b = (int *)malloc(pq_2_size * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < pq_1_size; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    } 
    for (int j = pq_1_size; j < M; j++) {
        b[j] = j;      << j is in range M/2 .. M-1 but must be in range 0..M/2-1
```

This means you are writing out of bounds for the second array which causes undefined behaviour.
You must adjust the index accordingly:

```c
    for (int j = pq_1_size; j < M; j++) {
        b[j-pq_1_size] = j;
```

or

```c
    for (int j = 0; j < pq_2_size; j++) {
        b[j] = j+pq_1_size;
```

Regarding your questions:

1. Why the second heap is always 0?
   That is just by accident. Memory allocated via `malloc` has no determined content. It can contain any values. You cannot rely on anything. As your loop does not touch the correct elements of that memory, you get these "random" values.
2. Why does it work if you use an initialized array?
   If you use

```c
int b[5] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

you have an array that contains the provided values starting from index 0.

Comment: thank you soo much. I can't tell you how grateful I am. i wasn't expecting such an inattentive mistake though.